# ADB logs bug report analysis

Tags: android, exception, error-handling, adb, bug-reporting

How to analyse the bug report, ANR in **POWEROFF** and **ON** senarios in android mobile and TV applications

1. Tried to analyse the crash using ADB logs.
2. Tried to get the class names in the logs.

Issues:

- Unable to find the class names in ADB logs as the names are encrypted.
- some errors does not have any data about the crashes.(Eg: Input dispatching timeout)

Required:

Need to analyse the detailed explanation about the ANR with bug report.

Comment: If you have used proguard to obfuscate the app you automatically got a mapping file which can be used to deobfuscate e.g. a stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to find the class names in ADB logs as the names are encrypted.
> some errors does not have any data about the crashes.(Eg: Input dispatching timeout)

Generally, unlike crashes, there is no useful backtrace in the adb logcat for ANRs.

However, for ANRs, you can pull the `/data/anr/traces.txt` and find some useful information inside the `traces.txt`, please refer to [Pull anr traces file](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr#trace-files)

Then if you find the stack trace inside the `traces.txt` is obfuscated, then you can use your mapping file and [retrace tool](https://developer.android.com/tools/retrace) to [Retracing stacktraces](https://developer.android.com/build/shrink-code#retracing) to analyze the original stack trace.